# discord.py rewrite: TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog

Tags: python, typeerror, discord, discord.py

As my bot is getting bigger, I'm trying to implement cogs, however I have ran across a problem. I have my whole code set up and ready, but for some weird reason I keep getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lauras\Desktop\Akagi Bot\main.py", line 107, in <module>
    bot.add_cog("cogs.fun")
  File "C:\Users\Lauras\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 477, in add_cog
    raise TypeError('cogs must derive from Cog')
TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog
```

My code on main.py looks like this:

```
   import discord
    import asyncio
    import typing
    import random
    import json
    import oauth
    from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(name='with Kaga :3',type=0))
    print (discord.__version__)
    print(f"{bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}")
    print ('Akagi is ready to serve the Commander :3 !')

    bot.add_cog("cogs.fun")
    bot.run(oauth.bot_token)
```

And the "fun" cog is as follows:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')

class FunCog:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def hug(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('has been hugged by', file=discord.File('iloveyou.gif'))
        pass


def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(FunCog(bot))
```

What could be the problem? I'm also using discord.py rewrite. Thanks !

Comment: Your cog isn't inheriting from Cog... the error is pretty clear.

Comment: I don't quite follow, what have I missed?

Comment: Replace `class Funcog:` into `class FunCog(commands.Cog):`.

Comment: I did, and I still get the same error :/ I assume bot.add_cog("cogs.fun") this line is causing problems somehow, no?

Comment: The way cogs work changed recently, you can find the documentation for these changes here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/cogs.html

Answer (score 4):

I recommend checking out https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html
This will help you get a better understanding of Cogs.

Firstly, you need to change `bot.add_cog("cogs.fun")` to `bot.load_extension("cogs.fun")`

This isn't necessary but you don't need to define `bot` again. 
Change `def setup(bot: commands.Bot):` to `def setup(bot):`

You will also need to change `class FunCog:` to `class FunCog(commands.Cog):`

I recommend staying up to date with changes when new updates come out for the rewrite version. Here is a quick look into an example of a [working cog file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpTKx.png).
Hope this helped! Max.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @Ellisein for helping me out with the `class FunCog(commands.Cog):` string of code. Another thing that helped me to fix the code was to replace `bot.add_cog("cogs.fun")` in the main.py with the `bot.load_extension("cogs.fun")` !