# discord.py discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'commands.help' raised an error: TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am having issues in loading my cogs.

I am trying to connect 'help.py' with my bot main file  'program.py'

`TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog`

[image]

Here is my code

Program.py - main bot file

```
import discord
import json
import os
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

with open('appsettings.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    token = data["token"]
    
intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, help_command=None, case_insensitive=True)



async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./commands'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'commands.{filename[:-3]}')


async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start(token)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    latency = round(bot.latency * 1000)
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.add_field(name=f"Opóźnienie bota wynosi: {latency}ms", value="", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
asyncio.run(main())
```

help.py - second file

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class HelpCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def help(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(title=" ̨ ", description="*Oto aktualna lista dostępnych komend bota:*", color=discord.Color.dark_purple())

        command_list = [
            ("Moderacja", [
                ("!kick", "Wyrzuć użytkownika z serwera"),
                ("!ban", "Zbanuj użytkownika na serwerze"),
            ]),
            ("Muzyka", [
                ("!play", "Odtwórz utwór"),
                ("!skip", "Pomiń utwór"),
            ]),
            ("Inne", [
                ("!ping", "Sprawdź opóźnienie bota"),
                ("!help", "Wyświetl listę dostępnych komend"),
            ])
        ]

        for category, commands in command_list:
            command_values = ""
            for command, description in commands:
                command_values += f"{command} - {description}\n"
            embed.add_field(name=category, value=command_values, inline=False)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(help(bot))
```

I checked multiple Youtube Videos and some forums as well. I also looked through the Discord.py Documentation.
I just cannot seem to find a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py rewrite: TypeError: cogs must derive from Cog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231877/discord-py-rewrite-typeerror-cogs-must-derive-from-cog)

Comment: @Dominik Unfortunately no, I've seen it before and tried everything

Answer (score 0):

Hello to you in the setup function of your cog you need to put your cog class:

```py
async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(your class cog(bot))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).